# Webdriver-manager error: Unable to create session with *my config*

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I run into the following problem after updating webdriver-manager:

> E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from

my config is printed here

webdriver-manager Version: 12.1.5
Node Version: 10.15.3
Protractor Version: 5.4.2
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System and Version: Win 7 / Ubuntu

This is my config file which worked for the last 1.5 years:

```
exports.config = {
    "seleniumAddress": "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    "seleniumPort": "4444",
    "capabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "unexpectedAlertBehaviour": "accept",
        "perform": "ANY",
        "version": "ANY",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "perfLoggingPrefs": {
               "traceCategories": "blink.console,devtools.timeline,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,benchmark"
           },
            "prefs": {
                "credentials_enable_service": false
            },
            "args": ["--headless", "--window-size=800,1080", "--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources", "--no-sandbox", "--test-type=browser", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--enable-gpu-benchmarking", "--enable-thread-composting" , "--start-maximized"]
        },
        "loggingPrefs": { "performance": "ALL" }
    },
    "jasmineNodeOpts": {
        "showColors": true,
        "defaultTimeoutInterval": 9999999
    },
    "allScriptsTimeout": 200000,
    "params": {
        "perf": {
            "selenium": { "protocol": "http:", "slashes": true, "auth": null, "host": "localhost:4444", "port": 4444, "hostname": "localhost", "hash": null, "search": null, "query": null, "pathname": "/wd/hub", "path": "/wd/hub", "href": "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" },
            "browsers": [{
                "browserName": "chrome", 
                "chromeOptions": { 
                    "perfLoggingPrefs": { 
                        "traceCategories": "blink.console,devtools.timeline,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,benchmark" 
                        },
                    "args": ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources", "--no-sandbox", "--test-type=browser", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]         
                },
                "loggingPrefs": { "performance": "ALL" }
            }],
            "debugBrowser": false, 
            "actions": ["scroll"],
            "metrics": ["TimelineMetrics", "ChromeTracingMetrics", "RafRenderingStats", "NetworkTimings", "NetworkResources"],
            "metricOptions": {}
        },
        "warmup": false,
        "agilar" : false
    }
}
```

I know the file is a mess and it's more or less googled together, but it worked. Can you point me to what is causing this problem?

Comment: I can see you are running headlessly, is this on docker or some other container?

Comment: Please show the whole error message.

Comment: Which version of chrome browser installed on machine?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Is selenium server up and running at default address 
 "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" . If it's not , start it by running : webdriver-manager start. Assuming you have webdriver-manager installed already.

Also I dont think you need to define seleniumPort when  you have selenium address property given already in config. So remove this property "seleniumPort": "4444" from config.